# Prestashop - Strict Standards if I install a module

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In Prestashop 1.6.1.13, when I create an order from the admin panel, and I search for products to add to it, I have this php error and I can't search any product:

```
Strict Standards: Declaration of Product::_getCustomizationFieldsNLabels() 
should be compatible with ProductCore::_getCustomizationFieldsNLabels($product_id, $id_shop = NULL) 
in /web/htdocs/www.lab-biocompany.com/home/eshop/override/classes/Product.php on line 810

Strict Standards: Declaration of Product::_createLabel() 
should be compatible with ProductCore::_createLabel($languages, $type) 
in /web/htdocs/www.lab-biocompany.com/home/eshop/override/classes/Product.php on line 810

Strict Standards: Declaration of Product::getCustomizationFields() 
should be compatible with ProductCore::getCustomizationFields($id_lang = false, $id_shop = NULL) 
in /web/htdocs/www.lab-biocompany.com/home/eshop/override/classes/Product.php on line 810
```

I have this issue if I install a module 'A'. If I uninstall the module 'A', I haven't the issue. But this module doesn't override the class Product, that instead is overrided by another module. How is it possible?

However the module 'A' has two overrides of two controllers instead. But they are unrelated to the Product class.

**Update 1**

I solved this problem setting 'Disable all overrides' to 'No' in the Prestashop Settings.

Now I can search products but I can't add them to the order. I get this error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started 
at /var/www/html/prestashop-1.6/prestashop/controllers/admin/AdminCartsController.php:481) 
in /var/www/html/prestashop-1.6/prestashop/classes/controller/AdminController.php on line 1829
```

and it happens when my custom module 'A' is installed. If I delete del folder 'override' from the module and I install it, I get the same error.

**Update 2**

Solved. My error was that in the principal file of my module I write this code (in order to see php errors) before the beginning of the class:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

class MyModule extends Module {
...
}
```

Deleting these three lines, all works fine.

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Anyway, there was a problem with the overridden methods... The warnings are clear, fix the methods parameters and everything should going ok :)

Comment: PHP 7.0.17. Now I have this other warning...

Comment: What you did is not a fix you're just suppresing errors.

Comment: Deleting those three lines all works fine. So, those three lines should not be before the declaration of the class of the module.